# What are your most common uses for regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I'm building up a library of filters for a validation class in PHP, some of them using regular expressions. I have a lot of filters in mind, but I also don't want to potentially miss any. What do you most often use regular expressions to check? What are some of the not-so-common things that you've had to check that would still be useful in a library? Note: I'm not looking for the actual regex code, just what you use it for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex should be strongly tested with their expected use cases.
Hence, it may be difficult to develop a complete and general library.
I would aim for a library of functions you know you need now.
Then add to this list later, when you have proper test cases.

That said, here are some common use cases:

Numeric Data
Phone numbers
Dates
Zip codes
SSN

Comment: When you are making your library don't forget that at least a couple of the things on this list vary based on locale.

Answer (score 1):

so you're looking for the type regular expressions we use for validating?

telephone (various international formats), postal code, zip code, credit card #s, email, dates, digits, ssn, urls (http, ftp, ...)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nescio's answers...

- Passwords
- Email addresses
- Disallowing characters various
  charters in text fields like
  non-alphanumeric characters

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection attack patterns

```
 '[\s]*--
```

Password Strength

```
 ((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,255})
```

Comment: SQL injection should be countered by bound parameters, not attempting to clean up the data.

Comment: Bound parameters won't help you catch the attempt and nuke the jackass who tried it, it will just error out. If you want to catch a person trying to hack you you've got to check your input. You can then use bound parameters for extra safety.

Answer (score 1):

My main uses for regular expression are:

- pulling apart text
- selecting lines in input
- validating formats
- analyzing/sanitizing input
- parsing
- providing expansive customization (allowing "configurable configurations", shortcuts,...)

A number of these things overlap. But it all has to do with human input. Machine readable and human readable are two different things. Regular expressions help us deal with human-oriented (that we know something about) stuff without needing a complete grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of my RE use is fixing up data given to me by various sources into a standardized format. A lot of exporting excel docs as CSV or tab delimited and then running through a bunch of RE transformations in TextPad.

Answer (score 0):

Please see Abigail's canonical Regexp::Common.

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common